understand complex dates in a column which are in the format "Mon, Apr 1, 2024, 08:48:09 PM GMT+8" in a dataframe column
I have two columns which has Date created and Date modified. Is there a way for reading the dates and find difference between them in days.. eg dataset is as follows:
Date created:    Mon, Apr 1, 2024, 09:09:48 PM
Date Modified.   Wed, May 8, 2024, 12:01:43 AM
Answer should be xx days.
I tried to split the column using:
date_created = df['Created date'].str.split(',', expand=True)

I am getting this output, but again I don't understand how to interpret.


 Dec 5



 Apr 1



 Apr 22



Is there a better way to do it?

Got the answer, posting it for anyone looking for it:
from datetime import datetime

date_format = "%a, %b %d, %Y, %I:%M:%S %p"

date1 = datetime.strptime("Mon, Apr 1, 2024, 09:09:48 PM", date_format)
date2 = datetime.strptime("Wed, May 8, 2024, 12:01:43 AM", date_format)

day_difference = (date2 - date1).days
print("Day difference:", day_difference)


so, what happened to the "GMT+8"? also, in the question you suggested using pandas?
